# How do I create a UITableView that loads 2 custom cells in one row in objective c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

Trying to mimic the UITableView in image below (at least that's what I think it is). It looks like it's using custom table view cells and loaded two cells per row. When I scroll on the app the data for what I think are two separate cells load at the same time.

If my assumption above is correct how would I go about creating a similar thing in my app? e.g. 2 custom cells 1 row.

or is there any commonly used method of creating a table like the one below.

Also how is the recommended refine row added? Could this just be another custom cell loaded into the UITableView?

Please help me under. My ultimate goal is to build a view like the one in the image and load all my data from the data base.

Thanks for your time
Kind regards

[image]

Comment: you can use only one cell, but have two separate image views e.g leftImageview & rightImageView.

Comment: You should use uicollectionview .

Comment: @RatikantaPatra is correct, you have to create your custom cell with 2 UIImageView.

Comment: Levi and Emilio is correct Use Collection view instated of Table view refer this link for more detail of Collection view http://www.raizlabs.com/2013/10/animating_items_uicollectionview/      hope this help you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you to use UICollectionView for recreating this project. I am quite sure that it was used in the screenshot and it also gives you much more methods to handle the customization of each element in the collection view. There are a bunch of great methods for CollectionView to define the header, footer and background as well as for object inside each view.

Answer (score 2):

If you want a grid-like component, use [UICollectionView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UICollectionView_class/Reference/Reference.html) instead of UITableView.